# Qual finalidade da utilização de ponteiros e alocação em c/c++

Tags: c, c++, alocação

Gostaria de entender o que são ponteiros de uma forma genérica e sua utilização, vejo códigos mais simples como cadastramento que eu mesmo faço no codeblocks rodar tranquilamente sem eles.
Da mesma forma estou com dúvida sobre alocação, quando estava tendo c na faculdade no máximo eu alocava estruturas, por quê? Nunca parei pra fazer essas perguntas, qual motivo/objetivo dos ponteiros e alocação?

Comment: quando você fala de "alocação" você se refere a alocação dinâmica, estática ou ambos?

Comment: Eu declarava a Estrutura como ponteiro e fazia nome_estrutura=malloc(sizeof(Estrutura)).

Comment: eu só sabia que tinha que fazer isso pra funcionar, quando estava aprendendo c, em c++ não tenho mínima ideia. deve ser algo como new, mas tmb não sei o motivo.

Comment: Pontei uma resposta, se ainda restar alguma dúvida sobre ponteiros e alocação dinâmica coloque um comentário que eu edito para complementar a resposta

Comment: Já que você está também perguntando sobre C++, hoje em dia, dificilmente precisa-se dar um 'new'. Os containers fazem tudo sem você usar ponteiros (internamente é usado). Dê uma pesquisada a respeito de containers em C++, como vector, map, e etc

Comment: Então o meu problema é como fazer isso, eu estou por exemplo fazendo um programa que lê 2 conjuntos, na classe eu declaro por exemplo um vetor float que tem [100] posições para eu poder armazenar os números digitados, como eu faria pra alocar dinamicamente isso? usando new por exemplo, devo alocar o objeto ou a variável? isso que pra mim fica difícil visualizar e até mesmo executar.@H.Lima

Comment: Se a sua pergunta é sobre alocação dinamica, torne isso claro editando-a, e detalhando as suas dúvidas. Da forma que está não consigo perceber exatamente o que você está perguntando e o que você realmente quer dizer com "alocação"

Comment: Eu quero entender de maneira geral o que é alocação / ponteiros, achei que tinha colocado tudo na pergunta. Mas o que eu disse nos comentários parece ser tópico pra outro assunto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde Vitor,

Vou dividir a resposta em duas partes pra ficar mais claro.

- **Alocação dinâmica de memória**

A principal vantagem da alocação dinâmica é trabalhar apenas com a quantidade necessária de memória, evitando assim o desperdício da mesma.

Exemplo:

Vamos supor que queremos fazer uma aplicação simples que cadastre uma quantidade N de alunos, sendo N um número desconhecido.

```
typedef struct{

char nomeAluno[30];
int idadeAluno;

}cadastroAluno;

int main(){

cadastroAluno novoAluno[100];


 return 0;
}
```

O trecho de código acima se trata de uma `alocação estática` de memória, onde criamos uma determinada `struct` e em seguida temos um vetor de 100 posições desse tipo de dado, o que significa que, sempre que a aplicação rodar, ela vai alocar a quantidade de memória equivalente a 100 vezes meu `struct`, o que nem sempre é conveniente. Por que alocar 100 espaços de `struct` se você não usa toda essa quantidade?

É nesse contexto que a `alocação dinâmica` de memória se faz necessária. Uma vez que você pode reservar somente o espaço necessário para atender a sua necessidade e evitar desperdício de memória.

- **Ponteiros**

Os ponteiros são ferramentas para manipulação de memória de forma direta, uma vez que é um tipo de dado que recebe endereços de memória como parâmetro e os acessa diretamente.

O grande diferencial do seu uso é ganho de desempenho do programa.